# convert very large calculation into currency total

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert the following float calculation into a currency figure.

```
3.738021952517549e+16
```

The following code below

```
'${:,.2f}'.format(3.738021952517549e+16)
```

outputs...

```
'$37,380,219,525,175,488.00'
```

This total should be in the low trillions.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting output of $3,738,021,952,517.48

Comment: But that would be `3.7e+12` not `3.7e+16`? are you looking for dividing the number by `1e4` before format?

Comment: perhaps.  I may have to go back and review the previous code for miscalculation.  My apologies very new but experimenting with a very large dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that a trillion has "12 zeros".

```
print('${:,.2f}'.format(3.738021952517549e+12))
```

Output:

```
$3,738,021,952,517.55
```

Comment: ok thanks! so with a large calculation the figure after the "+" is the number of zeroes?

Comment: This format is called [scientific notation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html).  Python uses a special syntax to write numbers in Scientific notation. For example, 0.000000123 can be written as 1.23E-7. The letter E is called exponent and it doesn't matter whether you use e or E.

Comment: very helpful! thank you for the explanation.